# Easiest way to do remote calls between a C++ program and a .NET program

Tags: .net, c++, remoting

I have a .NET program running in the background and need to create a Windows Shell Extension that can communicate with that program. At first I thought I would create my Shell Extension in .NET and used IpcServerChannel and IpcClientChannel to make remote calls between server (.NET program) and client (.NET Shell Exension). This was really simple to do and worked fine really quick.

Now I realize that creating the Shell Extension in .NET is not such a good idea as it can fail to load in some cases (if a .NET 1.0 Shell Extension would be loaded first for example). I think I might go the C++ route then, but in that case is there a simple way to make my C++ Shell Extension do remote calls to my .NET Program ? Or do you have any other idea to make my two programs communicate (I'd prefer if I didn't have to design a communication protocol and could just drop in a library).

Thanks !

Comment: Can't you use C++/CLI for .NET interop?

Comment: I don't think so : this would make the Shell Extension load a .NET framework wouldn't it ? This is what I need to prevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could try `SendMessage(WM_COPYDATA)`.

But then, if you are into it, it would be far more extensible (and maintenable) do just do a named pipe or a local inet socket. Actually, designing a communication protocol is not as difficult as it sounds: just send a serialized struct with the parameters and wait for a serialized reply. Then handle the timeouts and format errors, and done!

Comment: Well, designing the communication protocol is not difficult, making it work reliably is more tough. I've done my share of this kind of work in the past and would prefer avoiding this. (for example : I would need control caracters to serialize the struct, but then need a way to escape those caracters in case I need them. And oops, now I also need to think about security, buffer overflows, ...). As Roger Murtaugh would put it : I'm too old for this shit!

Comment: Actually, you don't need to escape anything unless you want your protocol to be human readable. For example, limit the serializable data types to INT, STRING and DOUBLE, then the string has the length followed by the actual data (ANSI, UNICODE, UTF-8, just pick one). Then when you serialize an struct just concatenate all the data together. And if you serialize an array, put the number of items first, and then the items themselves. Granted, there are some tricky bits here and there, but not worse than doing C++/CLI for example...

Comment: I finnaly wrote the Shell Extension in .NET, so I didn't have to do remote call between C++ and .NET, but it looks as though you answer is the way to go